# How to save an object in PHP and access it everywhere?

Tags: php, global-variables

I am new to PHP and I want to save an object from this class which I can access in my webservice this object hold a sessions id which can be used for calling an API:

MyObject.php:

```
class MyObject {
private $sessionId = '';

private function __construct(){
    $this->sessionId = '';
}

public static function getInstance() {
    if (!$GLOBALS['MyObject']) {
        echo 'creating new instance';
        $GLOBALS['MyObject'] = new MyObject();
    }
    return $GLOBALS['MyObject'];
}

public function getSessionsId() {
    if ($GLOBALS['MyObject']->sessionId == '') {
        // Do curl to get key (works)
        if (!curl_errno($curlCall)) {
            $jsonObj = json_decode($result);
            $sessionID = $jsonObj->session_id;
            $GLOBALS['MyObject']->sessionId = $sessionID;
        }
    }
    return $GLOBALS['MyObject']->sessionId;
}
```

}

Webservice GetKey.php

```
include 'MyObject.php';

    $instance = MyObject::getInstance();
    echo $instance->getSessionsId();
```

The I visit the GetKey.php file it always echoes 'creating new instance'

Comment: that's because `$GLOBALS['MyObject']` is the wrong superglobal array
you need `$_SESSION['MyObject']` to hold the object within you session.

You also should check `if (isset($_SESSION['MyObject'])){..`

Comment: But I do not want to store it in the session of the user. The session id is needed for calling an API.

Comment: I added that to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you store in `$GLOBALS` will be destroyed when the page is loaded... that variable is available only when the `response` is being created...

You don't save an object and use it everywhere (for all users) .. you are in php :) and you can store it anywhere... but if you're in a function then it will be destroyed when you are outside the function...

And in webservices you don't use session because it won't exist at next operation call

In the case that you want to store that variable for multiple requests of the same user you can store it in `$_SESSION` and not in `$GLOBALS`...

In `PHP` everything is destroyed when the user gets the response... (only session is an exception)... a session is like in java or any other language... you have it / user and you can modify it at request time... you don't have something like `applicationScope` and store there everything for all users... everything is being recreated at every request

Comment: Using sessions would enable OP to do what he asks for.

Comment: he wants a singleton... can't you see? sessions are for users not for application

Comment: As far as I can understand, OP has an issue in his session generating 'a new instance' with every request he makes. This is solvable with session - Singleton or not.

Comment: in case of a webservice it's not true! please study this topic before arguing... and the instance is being recreated... session is for both server and client! if I clear my cache I won't have my instance at my next request... read about serialization and what a session means ...

Comment: The instance needs to be saved for the application. It holds a sessions id to access an API. Sorry for not being clear, I added it to my question.

Comment: Edited my answer... first, you said that you want to use this class as a webservice or something like that

Comment: That's what the  GetKey.php is for. That is the webservice I made. It needs to access an API. Which will be done in MyObject.php

Comment: So you are saying there is nothing in PHP that can be saved in the application without using a user session?

Comment: The first revision of the question was clear enough - at least for some.

Comment: yes.. there isn't... because `php` is not like `java` or `c#`... it's running only to parse the php and give you a response and that's it.. that's the end of it :) `java` or `c#` is running all the time ... you can even store everything in static variables and give it to all users :)... in php side.. apache is running all the time, getting the request and accesing your php file

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will use something like memcache to save it in.

Comment: you can use anything.. even store it in database as json and reload it again at each request... the getInstance will be used to get your reference at every request.. if you want to store a state... otherwise you don't have to use anything...